# Optimization with Calculus

Tags: calculus, optimization

This one has me bugged big time.
An architect needs to design a rectangular room with an area of 89ft^2. What dimensions should he use in order to minimize the perimeter? Round to the nearest hundredth.

I began with 
$P=2x+2y$

$89=xy$

$y=89/x$

$P=2x+2(89/x)$

$P'=2-178/x^2$

And the answer I got was $+√89,-√89$, but I don't know if the dimensions would be $9.434$ by $9.434$ or if this answer or my method even makes sense? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your answer is correct, but you have to remember that this problem is "real world", so the positive is the only important answer. Don't forget to round to the correct place as well.

Comment: It does make sense, although I would also check that $P''>0$ there. But you don't have to do it.

Comment: Thank you both for your help, for some reason I just felt very uncomfortable with that problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct, although you should typically check to make sure that you've found a maximum and not a minimum. You can use the second derivative for this. It should be intuitively clear, though, that the answer will be a square room.

Also, the dimensions are not 9.434 by 9.434, but 9.43' by 9.43': you were missing units, and the problem asks to round to the nearest hundredth.